# AsyncTask doInBackground to return multiple strings

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to build a very basic weather app in android studio. I am using AsyncClass to return multiple strings.

As you can see in the code, I used a class named "Wrapper" that is used to store my strings so I can just return a class object and use it in the onPostExecute method of the AsyncTask. The problem I am facing is that when I test the app, all of the returned Strings somehow are undefined (the default for the Wrapper class). This means the strings are not being updated in the doInBackground method and I can't seem to figure out why!

[My Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qExLQ.jpg)

```
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Can't connect to Google Play Services!");
    }
    private class Wrapper
    {
          String Temperature = "UNDEFINED";
         String city = "UNDEFINED";
         String country = "UNDEFINED";
    }

    private class GetWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Wrapper> {
        private TextView textView;

        public GetWeatherTask(TextView textView) {
            this.textView = textView;
        }

        @Override
        protected Wrapper doInBackground(String... strings) {
            Wrapper w = new Wrapper();
            String Temperature = "x";
            String city = "y";
            String country = "z";

            try {
                URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                InputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                String inputString;
                while ((inputString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(inputString);
                }

                JSONObject topLevel = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
                JSONObject main = topLevel.getJSONObject("main");
                JSONObject cityobj = topLevel.getJSONObject("city");
                Temperature = String.valueOf(main.getDouble("temp"));
                city = cityobj.getString("name");
               country = cityobj.getString("country");

                w.Temperature= Temperature;
                w.city= city;
                w.country=country;

                urlConnection.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return w;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Wrapper w) {
            textView.setText("Current Temperature: " + w.Temperature + " C" + (char) 0x00B0
                       +"\n" + "Current Location: "+ w.country +"\n" + "City: "+  w.city );
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

turned out that that I was using the wrong url in my code,I was using :
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=%f&lon=%f&units=%s&appid=%s

Instead I should've been using:

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=%f&lon=%f&units=%s&appid=%s

-aka instead of weather I should've been using forcast

Comment: sorry, will edit it now

Comment: In the catch blok put `return null;`. In `onPostExecute()` check if `w==null` before using it.

Comment: will do that now and update you

Comment: made a simple if else

Comment: made a simple if else
if it was null it will print object is null 
and when I ran it it displayed object is null

Comment: still I don't understand why the w object is null even though I initialize it

Comment: So there was a catch. Well investigate. Do you know which exception? And the value of `e.getMessage()`?

Comment: W is null because you returned a null. Because there was a catch.

Comment: yeah it's the JSON exception, WIll investigate the e.gettMesssge() and get back to you

Comment: 1) Would be nice to see the URL or the JSON itself. 2) Volley / Retrofit are cleaner ways of dealing with JSON from websites

Comment: You should first check what you get back from the server. If it is valid json. So inspect the value of `builder.toString()`.

Comment: this is the json 
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=35&lon=139&appid=7faccd86dfcd7b50a5da0bfb602193bb

Comment: That is irrelevant. You should inspect what i said. Do you really receive what you should?

Comment: doing it now :)

Comment: `builder.append(inputString);` That should be `builder.append(inputString + "\n");`.

Comment: checked the builder sting , it seems to be find as it contain the all of the json

Comment: why , can you please explain

Comment: You read lines in a loop. So you should add lines to the builder too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error starts here

```
JSONObject main = topLevel.getJSONObject("main");
```

Probably because the `topLevel` object has no `"main"` key.

```
{  
   "city":{  },
   "cod":"200",
   "message":0.1859,
   "cnt":40,
   "list":[  ]
}
```

Throw your JSON into here. https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

You'll notice that there are many, many `"main"` keys that are within the `"list"` element, but you have to parse those starting from `getJSONArray("list")`.

---

Basically, something like this

```
String city = "undefined";
String country = "undefined";
List<Double> temperatures = new ArrayList<Double>();

try {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
    JSONObject jCity = object.getJSONObject("city");
    city = jCity.getString("name");
    country = jCity.getString("country");

    JSONArray weatherList = object.getJSONArray("list");
    for (int i = 0; i < weatherList.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject listObject = weatherList.getJSONObject(i);
        double temp = listObject.getJSONObject("main").getDouble("temp");
        temperatures.add(temp);
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return new Wrapper(city, country, temperatures);
```

Comment: doesn't seem to be working when I edited how I parse the json

Comment: I've edited with code that works for me. You just have to edit your code to match it (mostly change the `Wrapper` class to take a List)

Comment: will try this and get back to you

Comment: I get an exception saying there is no value for list  
12-19 22:28:24.164 26414-26458/com.deshpande.locationdemo W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for list when I used your code

Comment: I'm sure that it worked for me. I copied the exact link you provided. And `Log.d("temps", String.valueOf(temperatures));` before the return shows me  `D/temps: [286.59, 286.9, 288.09, 288.37,...]`. So I think your problem is that the StringBuilder did not get all the data.

Comment: hummm, will try to investigate the code further before I ask anymore question

Answer (score 1):

After studying your code, either your try block is failing, which is returning your object, but empty, or there is something wrong with your JSON parsing. If you could show us the JSON you are trying to parse that would be a great help.

That being said, the fact that it is still showing as "UNDEFINED" is because that is how you initialised it, and becuase (the JSON parse is likely failing), the object is being returned in an un-edited state.

**EDIT:**

You are parsing the JSON wrong. You are trying to find an object called "main" in the top directory, however the main object only exists inside of an array called list!

Please look here for a more easy to see and visual representation: http://prntscr.com/dlhlrk

You can use this site to help visualise your JSON and create an appropriate soluton based upon it. https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Is this an answer? You could better post such remarks in comments.

Comment: Yes this does answer the question as to why the "UNDEFINED" was being shown, and no I cannot comment, as for some reason that is baffling to me, I cannot leave comments until my reputation is at 50.

Comment: this is the json 
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=35&lon=139&appid=7faccd86dfcd7b50a5da0bfb602193bb

Comment: You were much too late. The UNDEFINED problem was long solved by the added `return null;`.

Comment: Edited my answer @HummingDev

Comment: doesn't seem to be working when I edited how I parse the json
there are many main and I can't seem to parse the one I want

Comment: That is because "list" is an array, so you need to itterate over it to get each instance of main! If you just want the first one then do something like this:

JSONObject main = topLevel.getJSONArray("list").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("main");

Comment: will try that now

Comment: I get an exception saying there is no value for list

Comment: 12-19 22:28:24.164 26414-26458/com.deshpande.locationdemo W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for list

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the API you posted earlier ([api.openweathermap.org](http://api.openweathermap.org)) you are trying to access variables that don't exist. I suggest you have a look at what the API [returns](https://openweathermap.org/current#current_JSON) and try getting the variables one by one if you are getting a JSONException

EDIT:
What API you are using? In your initial post you said it was http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather but in a comment above you said it was http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast.

If you're using the weather API (as initially stated) you can use the below:

```
    @Override
    protected Wrapper doInBackground(String... strings) {
        Wrapper w = new Wrapper();

        try {
            URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            String inputString;
            while ((inputString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(inputString);
            }

            Log.d("JSON", builder.toString());

            JSONObject topLevel = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
            JSONObject main = topLevel.getJSONObject("main");
            JSONObject sys = topLevel.getJSONObject("sys");

            w.Temperature = String.valueOf(main.getDouble("temp"));
            w.city = topLevel.getString("name");
            w.country = sys.getString("country");

            urlConnection.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return w;
    }
```

Comment: strange I don't think I'm parsing the json wrong 
will double check now

Comment: thanks man, already figured it out 
had four projects open at the same time which made me lose track of which link is which